# Search in MacMail

Tags: email, indexing, spotlight

I am running OS X 10.11.6 and MacMail 9.3 can not search my emails.
I 'rebuilt' my mailboxes and rebuilt my SpotLight indexes.

MacMail always reports 'Zero matches for search'.

Spotlight is saving in 'Store-V2', while the 'Envelope' indexes are in 'V3'.

What could be wrong?

[image]

[image]

```
$ pwd
/Users/davidlaxer/Library/Mail/V3/MailData
(base) MacBook-Pro:MailData davidlaxer$ ls -lrt Env*
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 davidlaxer  staff  86241280 May 10 10:31 Envelope Index
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 davidlaxer  staff     32768 May 10 11:20 Envelope Index-shm
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 davidlaxer  staff   1512072 May 10 11:46 Envelope Index-wal

$ sudo du -g /.Spotlight-V100/
Password:
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.assisted_import_post
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.assisted_import_pre
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.corespotlight
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.health_check
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.live
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.live_priority
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.live_system
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.live_user
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.migration
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.migration_secondchance
0   /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.scan
14  /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039
14  /.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2
14  /.Spotlight-V100/

 sudo ls -lRt /.Spotlight-V100/
total 8
drwx------  3 root  wheel   102 May  5 08:27 Store-V2
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  4001 May  5 08:27 VolumeConfiguration.plist

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2:
total 0
drwx------  119 root  wheel  4046 May 10 11:50 CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039:
total 28512848
-rw-------  1 root  wheel   261361664 May 10 11:51 .store.db
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        6554 May 10 11:51 live.4.indexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       65536 May 10 11:51 live.4.indexIds
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        7452 May 10 11:51 journalAttr.153
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     4614377 May 10 11:50 0.indexGroups
drwx------  3 root  wheel         102 May 10 11:50 journals.health_check
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:50 0.indexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:50 tmp.spotlight.state
drwx------  3 root  wheel         102 May 10 11:46 journals.assisted_import_pre
-rw-------  1 root  wheel          62 May 10 11:45 live.1.indexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel         616 May 10 11:45 live.1.indexIds
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:45 live.1.indexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    33554432 May 10 11:29 0.directoryStoreFile
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     4194304 May 10 11:29 live.0.directoryStoreFile
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:29 live.0.indexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       65536 May 10 11:29 live.1.directoryStoreFile
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     1048576 May 10 11:29 live.3.directoryStoreFile
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:29 live.3.indexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       65536 May 10 11:29 live.4.directoryStoreFile
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    33554432 May 10 11:29 reverseDirectoryStore
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    25952256 May 10 11:29 0.directoryStoreFile.shadow
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     4614377 May 10 11:29 0.shadowIndexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:29 0.shadowIndexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel          28 May 10 11:29 indexState
drwx------  3 root  wheel         102 May 10 11:29 journals.assisted_import_post
drwx------  3 root  wheel         102 May 10 11:29 journals.live_system
drwx------  3 root  wheel         102 May 10 11:29 journals.live_user
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     2752512 May 10 11:29 live.0.directoryStoreFile.shadow
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     1144320 May 10 11:29 live.0.shadowIndexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:29 live.0.shadowIndexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        5952 May 10 11:29 live.1.directoryStoreFile.shadow
-rw-------  1 root  wheel          62 May 10 11:29 live.1.shadowIndexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:29 live.1.shadowIndexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel      786432 May 10 11:29 live.3.directoryStoreFile.shadow
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       45288 May 10 11:29 live.3.shadowIndexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:29 live.3.shadowIndexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       17664 May 10 11:29 live.4.directoryStoreFile.shadow
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           0 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexUpdates
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     8388608 May 10 11:29 live.4.shadowIndexArrays
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        1456 May 10 11:29 live.4.shadowIndexCompactDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       19532 May 10 11:29 live.4.shadowIndexDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        2932 May 10 11:29 live.4.shadowIndexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 11:29 live.4.shadowIndexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     2501400 May 10 11:29 live.4.shadowIndexPositionTable
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     2501400 May 10 11:29 live.4.shadowIndexTermIds
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    31719424 May 10 11:29 reverseDirectoryStore.shadow
-rw-------  1 root  wheel          33 May 10 11:29 reverseStore.updates
-rw-------  1 root  wheel   261361664 May 10 11:29 store.db
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           3 May 10 11:29 store.updates
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     8388608 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexArrays
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        2048 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexCompactDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       32896 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     4194304 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexPositionTable
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    16777216 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexPositions
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     8388608 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexPostings
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     4194304 May 10 11:29 live.4.indexTermIds
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel           4 May 10 11:29 shutdown_time
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     1144320 May 10 11:20 live.0.indexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    11443200 May 10 11:20 live.0.indexIds
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       45288 May 10 10:41 live.3.indexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel      452880 May 10 08:54 live.3.indexIds
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    19262912 May 10 08:50 live.3.indexArrays
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     4022314 May 10 08:50 live.3.indexCompactDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel      460544 May 10 08:50 live.3.indexDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel          31 May 10 08:50 live.3.indexUpdates
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    35174385 May 10 08:50 live.3.indexPositions
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     9377717 May 10 08:50 live.3.indexPostings
-rw-------  1 root  wheel       65536 May 10 08:16 live.2.directoryStoreFile
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 08:16 live.2.indexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        1792 May 10 08:16 live.2.directoryStoreFile.shadow
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           4 May 10 08:16 live.2.shadowIndexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 08:16 live.2.shadowIndexHead
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     5937408 May 10 08:16 live.1.indexArrays
-rw-------  1 root  wheel      732628 May 10 08:16 live.1.indexCompactDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel      722684 May 10 08:16 live.1.indexDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel          17 May 10 08:16 live.1.indexUpdates
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     1332150 May 10 08:16 live.1.indexPositions
-rw-------  1 root  wheel      381040 May 10 08:16 live.1.indexPostings
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        3277 May 10 08:16 live.2.indexGroups
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        2112 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexArrays
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           8 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexCompactDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        2056 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel          32 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexIds
-rw-------  1 root  wheel         704 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexPositionTable
-rw-------  1 root  wheel         704 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexTermIds
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexPostings
-rw-------  1 root  wheel          13 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexUpdates
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        4096 May 10 08:15 live.2.indexPositions
-rw-------  1 root  wheel   116111616 May 10 06:55 live.0.indexArrays
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    16341676 May 10 06:55 live.0.indexCompactDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     7297772 May 10 06:55 live.0.indexDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel         125 May 10 06:55 live.0.indexUpdates
-rw-------  1 root  wheel   233745118 May 10 06:55 live.0.indexPositions
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    92373248 May 10 06:55 live.0.indexPostings
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    46143768 May  9 17:44 0.indexIds
drwx------  3 root  wheel         102 May  8 15:29 journals.live_priority
-rw-------  1 root  wheel      814959 May  8 15:29 tmp.spotlight.loc
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  1863674176 May  7 15:28 0.indexArrays
-rw-------  1 root  wheel   421591410 May  7 15:28 0.indexCompactDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel    32731520 May  7 15:28 0.indexDirectory
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        1815 May  7 15:28 0.indexUpdates
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  9492016397 May  7 15:21 0.indexPositions
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  1462613059 May  7 15:21 0.indexPostings
drwx------  3 root  wheel         102 May  7 14:10 journals.scan
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           0 May  5 08:27 Cab.created
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           0 May  5 08:27 Lion.created
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           0 May  5 08:27 journalAttr.1
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           0 May  5 08:27 journalExclusion
drwx------  2 root  wheel          68 May  5 08:27 journals.corespotlight
drwx------  2 root  wheel          68 May  5 08:27 journals.live
drwx------  2 root  wheel          68 May  5 08:27 journals.migration
drwx------  2 root  wheel          68 May  5 08:27 journals.migration_secondchance
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel           4 May  5 08:27 store_generation
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           0 May  5 08:27 tmp.Cab
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           0 May  5 08:27 tmp.Lion
-rw-------  1 root  wheel           0 May  5 08:27 tmp.SnowLeopard

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.health_check:
total 0
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  0 May 10 11:50 retire.10586

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.assisted_import_pre:
total 0
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  0 May 10 11:46 retire.155623

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.assisted_import_post:
total 0
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  0 May 10 11:29 retire.372

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.live_system:
total 0
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  0 May 10 11:29 retire.359623

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.live_user:
total 0
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  0 May 10 11:29 retire.970891

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.live_priority:
total 0
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  0 May  8 15:29 retire.272870

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.scan:
total 0
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  0 May  7 14:10 retire.5816751

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.corespotlight:

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.live:

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.migration:

/.Spotlight-V100//Store-V2/CD1CE8CA-B264-41BC-909A-ACD3AE66F039/journals.migration_secondchance:
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The directory ~/Library/Metadata/CoreSpotlight/ was missing.
2. /private/var/folders had directories owned by a non-existent user.
   Clearly, the disk cloning had issues.
   The solution was to do a clean reinstall the OS and use the migration assistant.